# How to simplify the given equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have trouble to understand a simplification I found online.

[image]

Equation that has to be simplified:

$\frac{dTC(Q)}{dQ}=\frac{-SD}{Q^{2}}+\frac{HD}{2P^{2}} [(P(1-\beta) - D)(1+2\beta)+\beta ^{2}(P-D)]+(a-\frac{D}{P}-\frac{\beta D}{P})^{2}\frac{H}{2} = 0$

Equation that is simplified:

$Q = \sqrt{\frac{2SDP}{H[P-(1+\beta +\beta ^{2})D]}}$

I don't understand how you get the second equation out of the first one...

Can someone help me?

Help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that the last factor in book is $\displaystyle \frac{H}{2}\left(1-\frac{D}{P}-\frac{\beta D}{P}\right)^2$, not as you have written.

Multiplying equation by $2P^2Q^2$ we have $$-2SDP^2+HDQ^2\left[(P-\beta P-D)(1+2\beta)+\beta^2(P-D)\right]+HP^2Q^2\left(\frac{P-D-\beta D}{P}\right)^2=0$$Thus $$-2SDP^2+HDQ^2\left[P+\beta P-\beta^2P-D-2\beta D-\beta ^2 D\right]+HQ^2(P-D-\beta D)^2=0$$Factoring we have $$Q^2\left[D(P+\beta P-\beta^2P-D-2\beta D-\beta ^2 D)+(P-D-\beta D)^2\right]=\frac{2SDP^2}{H}$$Simplifying the brackets we get $$P^2-DP-\beta DP-\beta^2 DP=P\left[P-D(1+\beta+\beta^2)\right]$$Eventually $$Q^2=\frac{2SDP^2}{HP\left[P-D(1+\beta+\beta^2)\right]}\implies\boxed{Q=\sqrt{\frac{2SDP}{H\left[P-D(1+\beta+\beta^2)\right]}}}$$